# How to defer load render blocking css in next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

As you can see in the below next.js code I am trying to defer load the render blocking css by giving my main.css file path in href attribute but I am struggling to do it in next.js. What I want is after loading the critical css in _document.js  tag under  tag, to load the non-critical css which is not above the fold.

_app.js

```
import App from "next/app"
import Head from "next/head"
import React from "react"
import { observer, Provider } from 'mobx-react'
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import allStores from '../store'

export default class MyApp extends App {
componentDidMount = () => {
       
};
render() {
        const { Component, pageProps, header, footer,  } = this.props
        return (
            <>
                <Head >
                    <link rel="preload" href="path/to/main.css" as="style" 
                    onLoad="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'"></link>
                </Head>
                <Provider {...allStores}>
                    <Layout header={header}  footer={footer}>
                        <Component {...pageProps} />
                    </Layout>
                </Provider>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens currently with the code you wrote above? Does it not load at all? Does it load too soon?

Comment: Why not have the `<link rel="preload">` in your static HTML so the browser runs it immediately?

Comment: It does not load at all@weltschmerz

Answer (score 2):

Here's my current favorite solution, sourced from here:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12014#issuecomment-434534770

It results in two empty `<script></script>` tags in your head, but works.

```
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `</script><link rel='preload' href='style.css' as='style' onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'"/><script>`,
  }}
/>
```

The Next.js team indicated that a similar strategy is possible with their  component, but in practice, I was getting compilation errors:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8478#issuecomment-524332188

The error I received was:

> Error: Can only set one of `children` or `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Comment: React was stripping out the onload prop so this was how I was able to solve it

Answer (score 1):

as @chrishrtmn said at _document.js you can do like this:

> ```
> import Document, { Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
> import { CriticalCss } from '../components/CriticalCss';
>
> class NextDocument extends Document {
>   render() {
>     return (
>       <html>
>         <CriticalCssHead />
>         <body>
>           <Main />
>           <NextScript />
>         </body>
>       </html>
>     );
>   }
> }
>
> export default NextDocument;
> ```

as in your component you can put the CSS:

> ```
> import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
> import { join } from 'path';
>
> export interface Props {
>   assetPrefix?: string;
>   file: string;
>   nonce?: string;
> }
>
> export const InlineStyle: React.FC<Props> = ({ assetPrefix, file, nonce }) => {
>   const cssPath = join(process.cwd(), '.next', file);
>   const cssSource = readFileSync(cssPath, 'utf-8');
>   const html = { __html: cssSource };
>   const id = `${assetPrefix}/_next/${file}`;
>   return <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={html} data-href={id} nonce={nonce} />;
> };
> ```

I got the source for this code from the current repo:

https://github.com/JamieMason/nextjs-typescript-tailwind-critical-css

have a look here

https://github.com/JamieMason/nextjs-typescript-tailwind-critical-css/tree/master/components/CriticalCssHead

Answer (score -2):

Might have to move the `<Head>` into _document.js instead of _app.js according to the documentation.